# Outside a jQuery dollar function, another jQuery element function does not detect the matches of at and hashtags. Is it a jQuery bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first function uses dollar (`$`) which loops the functions/variables (`$slider`, `$.instagramFeed` and `slick`). At the function end, outside I created another function called `$("#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide > figcaption").each(function(e)`, which is based on @dean-meehan's code from [Wrapping css class to Hashtag(#) content & At(@) content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213743/8041366).

- I have moved the function to several parts inside the first function, but it does not work;
- I added `$(document).on` to the seconf function, but no effect;
- I added different variables with `$(document).on`, but no effect;
- I removed `e` from `function(e)` and changed from `$("#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide > figcaption")` to `$(figcaption")`, no effect.

I tested with Firefox's Console's "Run", the function worked and detected the matches of at and hashtags.

Here is the minimal JavaScript code:

```js
(function ($) {

  // (...)

  const $slider = $('#instagram-feed-slider');

  // (...)

  $.instagramFeed({ // (...)  });

      // (...)

      $.each(slides, function(id, slide) { /* (...)*/ });
      $slider.on('init', function(slick) { /* (...)*/ }).slick({ /* (...)*/ });
    
    // (...) 

})(jQuery);

$("#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide > figcaption").each(function(e) 
{
  
  var words = $(this).text().split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
  {
    if (words[i].charAt(0) == "#") {
      words[i] = `<span class="hashtag">${words[i]}</span>`;
    }

    if (words[i].charAt(0) == "@") {
      words[i] = `<span class="at">${words[i]}</span>`;
    }
  }

  $(this).html(words.join(" "));

});
```

I also provide a snippet to run:

```js
(function ($) {
  
  // instagram username
  let username = "instagram";

  // slide count (max ever returned in callback data for a user is 12)
  let count = 12;

  // instagram feed slider
  const $slider = $('#instagram-feed-slider');

  // grab our instagram feed
  $.instagramFeed({
    'username': username,
    'container': false,
    'display_profile': false,
    'display_biography': true,
    'display_captions': true,
    'display_gallery': true,
    'display_igtv': true,
    'image_size': 160,
    'lazy_load': true,
    'callback': function(data) {

      // view raw instagram callback data
      // console.log(data);

      // latest owner timeline media not videos
      let media = data.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges;

      // slider media data
      let slides = {};

      // each media function
      $.each(media, function(i, item) {

        // current slide index
        let id = item.node.shortcode;
        
        // set slides id as object
        slides[id] = {};
        
        // get media caption from item
        let caption = item.node.edge_media_to_caption.edges;
        
        // check media caption is an array
        if($.isArray(caption)) {
        
           // check if we have caption array item 
           if(caption[0]) {
            
            // set caption as caption
            slides[id].caption = caption[0].node.text;
            
          }
        
        }
        
        // create thumb data object
        let thumb_data = {};

        // each item node thumb resource function
        $.each(item.node.thumbnail_resources, function(i, thumb) {

          // get thumb data width and src url
          thumb_data[thumb.config_width] = thumb.src;

          // add thumb data to our slides object
          slides[id].media = thumb_data;

        });

      });
      
      // use this console the our custom slick instagram slides data
      //console.log(slides);

      // iterator counter
      let iterator = 0;

      // each slides function
      $.each(slides, function(id, slide) {

        // add 1 to iterator
        iterator++;

        // if iterator is less than or equal to count
        if (iterator <= count) {

          // create our slide html string ( div > a > img )
          let slickSlide = '';
          
          // build our slick slide figure image with figcaption
          slickSlide += '<figure>';
          slickSlide += '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/' + id + '" target="_blank">';
          slickSlide += '<img src="' + slide.media[640] + '" alt=""/>';
          slickSlide += '</a>';
          
          // if we have a caption
          if(slide.caption) {
          
            // add figcaption to figure
            slickSlide += '<figcaption><p>' + slide.caption + '</p></figcaption>';
            
          }
          
          // close our slick slide figure
                    slickSlide += '</figure>';

          // append figure slide to instagram feed slider div
          $slider.append(slickSlide);

        }

      });

      // init slider with slick
      $slider.on('init', function(slick) {

        // do stuff here when slick initializes

        // slight delay so slick init completes render
        setTimeout(function() {

          // reveal the slider with opacity
          $slider.addClass('slick-reveal');

          // delay time .1 second
        }, 100);

        // then our slick options
      }).slick({
        mobileFirst: true,
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 4,
              slidesToScroll: 4,
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 6,
              slidesToScroll: 6
            }
          }
        ]
      });

    }

  });

})(jQuery);

$("#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide > figcaption").each(function(e) {
  //Get full string as words
  var words = $(this).text().split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].charAt(0) == "#") {
      words[i] = `<span class="hashtag">${words[i]}</span>`;
    }

    if (words[i].charAt(0) == "@") {
      words[i] = `<span class="at">${words[i]}</span>`;
    }
  }

  $(this).html(words.join(" "));

});
```

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#instagram-feed-slider
{
  height: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  width: 1024px;
}

#instagram-feed-slider.slick-initialized
{
  height: auto;
}

#instagram-feed-slider.slick-initialized.slick-reveal
{
  opacity: 1;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide
{
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide::before
{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide> a
{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide> a> img
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide:hover> a> img
{
  opacity: 0.25;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide> figcaption
{
  font-family: "Helvetica", serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  hyphens: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide:hover> figcaption
{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  text-align: center;
}

.at 
{
  color: #c1d72c;
}

.hashtag 
{
  color: #bda3f7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


  <div id="instagram-feed-slider"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.instagramFeed/1.4.1/jquery.instagramFeed.min.js"></script>
```

Or check my pen https://codepen.io/gusbemacbe/pen/dypzNYW. Go to the line 171 of JavaScript.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not at codepen.io. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I am very sorry! Done, @Barmar.

Comment: Loading the instagram feed is an asynchronous operation; you need to run the code in question *after* the images and figcaptions are created, not before.

Comment: Seems like you order a pizza, but you try to eat it before it is delivered. You need to call that code after the asynchronous function is run. So the code needs to run when the code that generates the slides is done.

Comment: @ChrisG, I also did it, but no effect.

Comment: Wrap the code in a function, then call the function in `$slider.on("init"`. Works fine for me. You can also look for the line that inserts `slide.caption` and replace that with `highlightStuff(slide.caption)`

Comment: Yes, I got it. I never thought to move the code to `slick` part. I moved only to InstagramFeed and slides functions. @dean-meehan's code does not match the at that does not have parentheses. Does `charAt` support regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.slick-slide` is a class that gets added by Slick on initialization of the carousel. So, `$("#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide > figcaption")` is returning an empty jQuery object. I'd recommend removing that class from the selector (i.e. `$("#instagram-feed-slider figcaption")`, or move that code block inside the `init` handler for slick.